# WordPress translation language error - New translations are available?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added the translation language manually in wp-content/

And I have updated the General Setting -> Site Language -> UK

But why does Wordpress keep telling me `New translations are available.`?

[image]

I came across this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142448/how-can-i-manually-upgrade-translations) and it had the same problem that I have. I have done exactly the same but it does not solve my problem.

Any ideas what else have I missed?

Comment: So did you click the update button?

Comment: @j08691 yes i did.

Comment: And what happens? Nothing?

Comment: @j08691 then I get to the 'Update Translations' page where it asks for '
Connection Information'. How can I have those info while I am working on my localhost?

Comment: My connection or self update setup works, but after updating the translations, which it says is doing and finishes, the update comes right back. Were you able to fix this?